# En un mismo formulario ¿Se podría cambiar el valor de una casilla dependiendo de otra?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysqli, aplicación-web

Tengo una tabla clientes que tiene su nombre y una entidad débil subordinada a ella, llamada obracivil, que tiene la localización además del nombre del cliente.

Tengo un formulario que tiene dos desplegables, uno con los nombres de los clientes (cliente), y otro (Obra) con los nombres de las localizaciones (tabla obracivil).

Me gustaría que al seleccionar un cliente, la casilla de las obras solo muestre las localizaciones asociadas a ese cliente, así solo podría seleccionar las localizaciones asociadas a ese cliente.

[image: Desplegables del formulario]

Adjunto parte del código.

```
<div class= "panel panel-primary">
<div class= "panel-heading" style="background-color:#0f31f0;text-align: center;"><b style="color: #ffffff">Añadir Movimiento</b></div>

<div class= "panel-body">
    <div class= "form_mov">


        <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top:5px;">
            <label for="emp" style="margin-right: 5px"><strong>Cliente</strong></label>
            <select class="form-control" id="emp" name="emp">
        <?php
            //vamos a buscar las empresas
            $res = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT nomEmp FROM cliente");
            if($res->num_rows > 0){
                while($a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                    echo "<option>";
                    echo $a_res['nomEmp'];
                    echo "</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top:5px;" name="CasillaObra" id="CasillaObra">
            <label for="local" style="margin-right: 5px"><strong>Obra</strong></label>
            <select class="form-control" id="local" name="local">
        <?php
            //vamos a buscar las obras
            //TODO: hacer con las obras solo del cliente ya seleccionado
            $res = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT localizacion FROM obracivil");
            if($res->num_rows > 0){
                while($a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                    echo "<option>";
                    echo $a_res['localizacion'];
                    echo "</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        </div>



        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" name="anadirMov" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top:10px; margin-inline:auto; ">Añadir Movimiento</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estoy usando HTML, Boostrap, Javascript, PHP y mysqli.

¿Es esto posible? Y si, es así ¿Cómo se podría hacer?.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Claro que es posible! investiga sobre ajax, porque vas a tener que comunicarte mediante eso a un backend que traiga esos datos y arme el segundo combo una vez seleccionado el primero.

Comment: Dependiendo de la cantidad de clientes, si es un proyecto no muy grande, no sería necesario utilizar Ajax, con que PHP cree un objeto dentro de un script con los nombres de los clientes (o IDs) y sus obras posibles, sería más que suficiente.
También necesitaría conocer como es la base de datos para poder darte una respuesta exacta, no obstante, te animo a que lo investigues por tu cuenta también con las pistas que te hemos dado :)

Comment: Vale lo investigaré ¡Gracias!

Comment: Buenas tardes, he estado mirando un poco de AJAX pero no lo he visto mucho con algo relacionado, entonces no se me ocurre bien como hacerlo. La base de datos será grande. Cliente tiene su nombre, y obracivil tiene el nombre del cliente y la localización de la propia obra. ¿Podríais ayudarme un poco más? ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Claro que si se puede en `js`  se utiliza el `null_fillSelect2`

es mas difícil en **`php`**

asignas el valor del `id` en común

**por ejemplo:**

```
  var idPlanta = $(#ddlPlanta.val)//asignas el valor del dll que quieres
```

y se lo pasasa otro, código de ejemplo:

```
NU_FillSelect2('ddlConcepto', 'ahorro.aspx', 'ddlListaConcepto', 'id_planta:' + idPlanta, { id: 'id_concepto', text: 'descripcion' });

$("#ddlConcepto").select2().change(function (e) {})
```

Comment: Buenos días y gracias por responder. Hay algunas cosas que no me han quedado claras, así que, si no te importa, te preguntaré. En primer lugar, el id común , supongo que será que dentro del div, ponga un input hidden y le ponga ese id¿Verdad? Porque así podría ponerle un valor. y por otro lado; he buscado la función, pero no la encuentro así que no se muy bien para qué es cada parámetro 'NU_FillSelect2('ddlConcepto', 'ahorro.aspx', 'ddlListaConcepto', 'id_planta:' + idPlanta, { id: 'id_concepto', text: 'descripcion' });'